# Do I have to replace the roof immediately after insurance payout?

Tags: mortgage, real-estate, home-ownership, home-insurance

I have a $8500 bid to replace the roof after hail damage.  Obviously, insurance isn't going to pay out all of it.  After the deductible and depreciation, I'm looking at $3700 payout.

Are they going to require the repairs to be made?  I certainly don't immediately have the cash to pay our share of the roof replacement.  Contractors won't accept a credit card so this puts us in a bind.

Not replacing the roof immediately isn't going to cause further damage so we really want to put the payout in savings and save up for our share and have it replaces in like 6 months.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Your insurance company can answer this question far better than anyone here.

Answer (score 5):

you'd certainly want to check your policy. For something with the impact as great as a roof, there may be a clause in the policy requiring the repair in order to maintain coverage. Look for wording that your coverage is limited or restricted until repairs are completed.

Depending on the coverage for your possessions, any additional claims, although unrelated to the roof, may also be voided.